# compiling shared library (old standard) with c++11 shared library

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-libraries, libraries, .so

I'm trying to compile a shared library (A) that uses another shared library (B).

The A library have to be compiled without adding `-std=c++11` option to g++ (because there are tons of code, and some things like `std::make_pair` will not work with the '11 standard).

For using the B library, the first one just `#include "B.h"` in one of its files, and then compile with `-I/path/inc -L/path/lib -lB`.

The library B is formed by a set of functions inside the `namespace B`, and includes some classes definitions in its own namespace (B::internals). The relation between functions and class is a static pointer in the global scope, initialized with an `__attribute__((constructor))`.

The problem is that this class (B::internals::classB) defines some `std::mutex` private attributes, and, following the include's chain:
libA -> libB -> `B::internals` -> `std::mutex`,
makes that when compiling libA without `-std=c++11` standard compilation fails.

However, libA never uses `B::internals`, so it should not be a problem mixing both libraries. Also, if the c++11 features are private attributes, why are they not hidden to libA?. Is there some pattern for hide `B::internals` to libA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a C++ idiom for hiding implementations details called [`Pimpl`](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/).

Also, the library compiled with different C++ options must not expose any `std` containers in its interface because their layout is different in different C++ versions.

Comment: And, what about having two headers, one for linking with libA and the other for compiling libB? Is there some trick like #ifdef for making this, or is piplm a standad de facto in the industry?

Comment: @marolafm It is up to you how to expose the API (C-style functions, interface + factory function, Pimpl), however, the implementation details should not be present in the headers.